# Bridge between Core PHP site and PHPBB

Tags: phpbb3

I want to add bridge between my PHP website and my **PhpBB3** forum, so that when user login in my website then he automatically logged-in into PHPBB forum or when he sign-up in my site then he automatically signed-up in Forum. I have seen many article about it but not able to find the correct one which can solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the session that the PHPBB forum uses for this integration.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '/var/www/clients/client9/web8/web/forums/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

$user->session_begin();
```

From here, you can use the `$user` object for your integration. For example, the code below will show you if your user is logged in or not.

```
if ($user->data['username'] == 'Anonymous')
{
    echo 'Please login!';
}
```

This uses the `Anonymous` user for validation, which PHPBB adds as the first user account when it is installed.